# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred

Tags: c#

I am getting the error **An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Forte Sender.exe** in my code. I have the understanding that this means there is an infinite loop in my code, but I cannot seem to find this loop. Here is my code:

Form1:

```
public partial class MainBox : Form
{
    //Making a name for the ApplicationProperties form. It can be opened when called.
    ApplicationProperties ApplicationPropertiesWindow = new ApplicationProperties();
    //All of the functions for form1 below.
```

Form2:

```
public partial class ApplicationProperties : Form
{
    MainBox MainBoxWindow = new MainBox();
    //All of the funcitons for form2 below.
```

So I have noticed that if I take out the `MainBox MainBoxWindow = new MainBox();` that the program will run correctly. But I need that instance there to call a function in Form1. How can I get around this problem? Either a different way to call the function or to solve the infinite loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, your `MainBox` creates an `ApplicationProperties`, which in turn creates a `MainBox`, which creates an `ApplicationProperties`, and so on ad infinitum. Obviously you need to break up this cycle.

As your code stands right now you would probably want to remove the `new MainBox()` for the properties form and inject it afterwards, for example:

```
ApplicationProperties ApplicationPropertiesWindow = new ApplicationProperties();
ApplicationPropertiesWindow.MainBoxWindow = this;
```

And

```
public partial class ApplicationProperties : Form
{
    public MainBox MainBoxWindow { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Very well explained answer, thank you. This worked out great for me.

Answer (score 2):

You just open one form and it opens another from it's constructor and it opens the first one again in t's contructor and so on...

Fields initializers executed right before constructor when an instance is created.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ApplicationProperties` class creates a `MainBox` object, and your `MainBox` object creates an `ApplicationProperties` object. This is the loop. Each call to `new` is another constructor call in that loop. The constructors call each other in term in something called mutual recursion, which leads to your stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You're Creating `MainBox`  Inside `ApplicationProperties` and `ApplicationProperties` inside `MainBox` this will keep on creating Instances resulting `StackOverFlowException`

To avoid this you could create Instances in `OnLoad` overridden method, but creating Instances mutually tied doesn't make sense did you mean to use the same reference?